# CXF interceptor - turn request body into an attachment

Tags: java, apache, request, cxf, attachment

I have a problem that some clients which integrate with my API are not by standards (of course :)).

So, some of the clients instead of adding a file attachment are sending the content of the file in the request body (with wrong headers). And this causes an exception from CXF (can't find boundary).

I have implemented an InInterceptor for checking the content. First I already change the content-type, otherwise CXF returns 415 error.

How can I now transform plain text input request body to an attachment?

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
    Map<String,List> map = (Map<String, List>)message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);
    if(url != null && url.indexOf("uploadFile") > 0) { //TODO && !Content-type = multipart/form-data
        message.remove(Message.CONTENT_TYPE);
        message.put(Message.CONTENT_TYPE, "multipart/form-data");
        map.put("content-type", Collections.singletonList("multipart/form-data"));
        message.put(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS, map);
    }

    InputStream is = message.getContent(InputStream.class);
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(is, writer, "UTF-8");
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String requestBody = writer.toString();
    System.out.println(requestBody);
}
```

What I noticed, that if the request is correct (file attached), input request looks like this (notice the boundary strings):

```
--g-fcgqFfRThi-YWVLasSjj8mvL2PJecFQq
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload__31e8f749_142e740a2c1__7fff_00000040.tmp"; filename="upload__31e8f749_142e740a2c1__7fff_00000040.tmp"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

FILE CONTENT

--g-fcgqFfRThi-YWVLasSjj8mvL2PJecFQq--
```

And if it is not correct (plain text in request body), input stream is just this:

```
FILE CONTENT
```

And this then causes the "boundary not found exception". Of course I am getting now "Stream closed" exception in this code, but this is just because I am in mode for finding a solution.

Comment: Where r u adding attachment to the message?

Comment: I don't. I would like to know how to do that :) Of course, only if the request is without an attachment and with request body.

Comment: did you get any solution ?i also had the same issue i cound not able to add multipart data  this is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56293017/apache-cxf-how-to-add-soap-attachment-mtom
if you have any link please send